# Create a new column by adding matching cell content in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello everyone I would need help in order to to fusionnate columns containt when there is a specific grep value inside.

Here is an exemple

```
Species COL1 COL2         COL3           COL4     COL5
SPf_1   4    f_G1         None           None     None
SP1     9    -_Haploviric -_unclassified f_G3     None
SP1     36   k_Orthorn    f_G7           None     None
SP2     90   k_Orthorn    f_G3           p_Pisuvi None
SP3     32   None         None           None     f_83
SP3     2    -_Ribovi     Cattus         None     None
SP4     89   None         None           None     None
```

and then I would like to add a new column called F_COL  where I put for each row the cell content with a `f_ pattern` on it. Note (I only have to check of `COL1-5` but not `Species` columns that can have f_ patterns also).

I should get :

```
Species COL1 COL2         COL3           COL4     COL5 F_COL
SPf_1     4    f_G1         None           None     None f_G1
SP1     9    -_Haploviric -_unclassified f_G3     None f_G3
SP1     36   k_Orthorn    f_G7           None     None f_G7
SP2     90   k_Orthorn    f_G3           p_Pisuvi None f_G3
SP3     32   None         None           None     f_83 f_83
SP3     2    -_Ribovi     Cattus         None     None NA
SP4     89   None         None           None     None NA
```

Does someone have an idea please ?

Here is the data in dictionnary format :

```
{'Species': {0: 'SPf_1', 1: 'SP1', 2: 'SP1', 3: 'SP2', 4: 'SP3', 5: 'SP3', 6: 'SP4'}, 'COL1': {0: 4, 1: 9, 2: 36, 3: 90, 4: 32, 5: 2, 6: 89}, 'COL2': {0: 'f_G1', 1: '-_Haploviric-', 2: 'k_Orthorn', 3: 'k_Orthorn', 4: 'None', 5: '-_Ribovi', 6: 'None'}, 'COL3': {0: 'None', 1: '_unclassified', 2: 'f_G7', 3: 'f_G3', 4: 'None', 5: 'Cattus', 6: 'None'}, 'COL4': {0: 'None', 1: 'f_G3', 2: 'None', 3: 'p_Pisuvi', 4: 'None', 5: 'None', 6: 'None'}, 'COL5': {0: 'None', 1: 'None', 2: 'None', 3: 'None', 4: 'f_83', 5: 'None', 6: 'None'}}
```

Comment: Can there be multiple cells in a single row containing `f_pattern` like values?

Comment: No, there is one unique f_pattern for each row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us `filter` and `stack` the columns from `COL1` to `COL5`, then `extract` the `f_pattern` strings followed by `groupby` + `first` on `level=0`

```
df.filter(regex='COL[1-5]').stack()\
  .str.extract(r'^(f_.*)', expand=False).groupby(level=0).first()
```

---

```
0    f_G1
1    f_G3
2    f_G7
3    f_G3
4    f_83
5    None
6    None
dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice, but maybe the regex doesn't need `^`. Not sure if OP meant that it must *start* with `f_`.

Comment: Thanks @tdy you are correct we could remove the start of line assertion :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def get_f_pattern(row):
    for value in row.values:
        if isinstance(value, str) and re.match(r'f_\w{2}', value):
            return value
    return 'NA'

df['F_COL'] = df.apply(get_f_pattern, axis=1)

df
  Species  COL1           COL2           COL3      COL4  COL5 F_COL
0   SPf_1     4           f_G1           None      None  None  f_G1
1     SP1     9  -_Haploviric-  _unclassified      f_G3  None  f_G3
2     SP1    36      k_Orthorn           f_G7      None  None  f_G7
3     SP2    90      k_Orthorn           f_G3  p_Pisuvi  None  f_G3
4     SP3    32           None           None      None  f_83  f_83
5     SP3     2       -_Ribovi         Cattus      None  None    NA
6     SP4    89           None           None      None  None    NA
```

This creates a function that given a row, run over all of its value and returns the first f_pattern it matches, otherwise 'NA'
Then we run `.apply` with `axis=1` to tell pandas to apply this function on all rows and assign the result to `F_COL`

Comment: In that case, you should just replace it with whatever check matches the pattern, `r'f_\w+'`, or `value.startswith('f_')`